# iAd suite: How to hide the basic banner?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I've implemented the iAd suite code and got everything working. However when the ad isn't correctly loaded the content view doesn't get resized (since the banner view space isn't needed anymore). Furthermore I want this also when a user purchases the "no-ad" version of my app. Then then banner should get removed at runtime. How can I do this? Here is my code (most of the part from iAd suite 1:1 copied):

//

```
#import "IAdViewController.h"

@interface IAdViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
// contentView's vertical bottom constraint, used to alter the contentView's vertical size when ads arrive
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint;

@end

@implementation IAdViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kInAppPurchaseNoAds] boolValue]){

        _bannerView = [[Singletons sharedInstance] bannerView];
        _bannerView.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:_bannerView];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self layoutAnimated:NO];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

//Handle the in app purchases
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)layoutAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;

    // all we need to do is ask the banner for a size that fits into the layout area we are using
    CGSize sizeForBanner = [_bannerView sizeThatFits:contentFrame.size];

    // compute the ad banner frame
    CGRect bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;
    if (_bannerView.bannerLoaded) {

        // bring the ad into view
        contentFrame.size.height -= sizeForBanner.height;   // shrink down content frame to fit the banner below it
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.size.height = sizeForBanner.height;
        bannerFrame.size.width = sizeForBanner.width;

        // if the ad is available and loaded, shrink down the content frame to fit the banner below it,
        // we do this by modifying the vertical bottom constraint constant to equal the banner's height
        //
        NSLayoutConstraint *verticalBottomConstraint = self.bottomConstraint;
        verticalBottomConstraint.constant = sizeForBanner.height;
        [self.view layoutSubviews];

    } else {
        // hide the banner off screen further off the bottom
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? 0.25 : 0.0 animations:^{
        _contentView.frame = contentFrame;
        [_contentView layoutIfNeeded];
        _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
    }];
}

- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kInAppPurchaseNoAds] boolValue]){
        [_bannerView removeFromSuperview];
        _bannerView.delegate = nil;
        _bannerView = nil;
        [self layoutAnimated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [self layoutAnimated:[UIView areAnimationsEnabled]];
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [self layoutAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailToReceiveAdWithError %@", error);
    [self layoutAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it´s in the Design Guides that you should animate the banner to move in and out. Also if it fails to load an ad you should move out and when an ad is loaded move in.

To move in use:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];

// Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen.

banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

To move out use:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

// Assumes the banner view is placed at the bottom of the screen.

banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

You can use notifications to fire these methods. Also when user purchased "no-ad" fire the move out notification. Also store a value in NSUserdefaults when user buys "no-ad" and make the move in method into an if-statement. And if the user purchased "no-ad" don t requests ads anymore of course.

P.S. I would use an ad mediation network like adMob or mopub to use multiple ad networks and set priorities live instead of using iAd only. iAd has very low fill rates, at least for most people especially in certain countries. With more ad networks you can reach higher fillrates. A good start would be adMob + iAd because adMob has a really high filtrate and for me at least, they pay much better. I get like 98% revenue from adMob and the rest from iAd... Also interstitials (Fullscreen ads) are paid much better than banners and it s really easy to implement. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set bottom constraint to 0 when ad is not available.

```
- (void)layoutAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;

    // all we need to do is ask the banner for a size that fits into the layout area we are using
    CGSize sizeForBanner = [_bannerView sizeThatFits:contentFrame.size];

    // compute the ad banner frame
    CGRect bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;
    if (_bannerView.bannerLoaded) {

        // bring the ad into view
        contentFrame.size.height -= sizeForBanner.height;   // shrink down content frame to fit the banner below it
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.size.height = sizeForBanner.height;
        bannerFrame.size.width = sizeForBanner.width;

        // if the ad is available and loaded, shrink down the content frame to fit the banner below it,
        // we do this by modifying the vertical bottom constraint constant to equal the banner's height
        //
        NSLayoutConstraint *verticalBottomConstraint = self.bottomConstraint;
        verticalBottomConstraint.constant = sizeForBanner.height;
        [self.view layoutSubviews];

    } else {
        // hide the banner off screen further off the bottom
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
        NSLayoutConstraint *verticalBottomConstraint = self.bottomConstraint;
        verticalBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
        [self.view layoutSubviews];
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? 0.25 : 0.0 animations:^{
        _contentView.frame = contentFrame;
        [_contentView layoutIfNeeded];
        _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
    }];
}
```